# Abstract data type (ADT) for truth table

Tags: abstract-data-type, truthtable

Just like there is a nice, common/generic, [ADT for Graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29).

Is there something for "truth tables"? I'm trying to find 'class' definitions from projects which already implement a truth table.

If not, how would you go about designing a (generic) truth table ADT?

UPDATE: As suggested in comments, here is what I came up with:

- Add (delete) a row: `TruthTable.add(input,output)` (the first row which gets added is used to extract the length (in bits) of inputs and output. All subsequent row additions are validated against this.) and `TruthTable.delete(input)`
- Get the output(image) for a given input:`TruthTable.output(input)` or `TruthTable.image(input)`
- Get all the inputs: `TruthTable.inputs` (Odometer ordering.)
- Get all outputs : `TruthTable.outputs` (Order according to ordering of inputs or odometer ordering?)
- See if a table is completely specified, ie, for all the 2<sup>n</sup> possible inputs, is an output specified: `TruthTable.completely_specified?`

Other specialized operations can be:

- Check if a truth table is invertible: `TruthTable.invertible?`
- Check if two tables are equivalent: `TT1 ==? TT2`

(I wish sometimes that programming languages allowed method names to end in a '?', for names of those methods which return a `Bool`)

Comment: Hmmm, I'd copy the approach taken in the Wikipedia article you point us towards, perhaps start by listing the operations on a truth table.  After that I'd stop and think some more about what to do next.  But, and this is pertinent to improving your question, how would you go about designing a generic truth table ADT ?  Share your thoughts, you might get helpful criticism and suggestions.